# Is the convention for reporting football results universal?

Tags: football, terminology

In Britain (and throughout Europe and the football-playing world), it is the normal convention to state the name of the home team first and the away team second. So when the results are read out on the radio the announcer will say, for example:

"Queens Park Rangers 2 Sheffield Wednesday 3".

(The match was played at the ground of QPR)

However I have been informed that such a convention is foreign to Americans. In the USA, the score of the winning side is always read out first.

Is this the case or not?

Comment: Also: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17589/which-team-is-mentioned-first-in-the-score-in-nba-games

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, the convention in the US is to report the winning team first.

Take [Wednesday's article](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/08/sports/yankees-adam-engel-white-sox.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fbaseball) in the New York Times on Tuesdays's Yankee-White Sox. matchup played at **Guaranteed Rate Field** (the home field of the White Sox).
The header reads "**YANKEES 7, WHITE SOX 3**," although the score isn't mentioned directly in the text.

Likewise, [Wednesday's article](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/08/sports/baseball/sal-romano-reds-mets.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fbaseball) on the Reds-Mets game (at the Mets' home field), lists the Reds first: "**REDS 3, METS 1**, and the copy matches.

> Sal Romano got the win in his New York homecoming, pitching into the seventh inning to lift the Cincinnati Reds *over the Mets, 6-1,* on Tuesday night in a game delayed by rain for 1 hour 40 minutes in the first inning. [emphasis added].

I added two examples from New York home teams to show it isn't a convention to list the local team first either. I would also note that in baseball, the away team always goes first and the home team second, so it would be very normal to always list *[away]-[home]*, although that isn't the case (see [today's article](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/10/sports/aroldis-chapman-yankees-rangers.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fbaseball) on the Yankee's home win, where the Yankees are listed first).

For a soccer example, I dug up this [2015 article](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/04/20/sports/soccer/a-late-goal-beats-new-york-city-fc.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fsoccer&action=click&contentCollection=soccer&region=stream&module=stream_unit&version=search&contentPlacement=5&pgtype=sectionfront) on the New York City F.C. vs. Portland Timbers game, which was [played on NYCFC's home turf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_New_York_City_FC_season).

In this article, the Timbers (away) are listed first in the header: "**TIMBERS 1, NEW YORK CITY F.C. 0** and in the copy:

> Dairon Asprilla scored a late second-half goal Sunday night, and the Portland Timbers beat New York City F.C., 1-0.

---

Anecdotally, growing up in America, I was always taught to list the winning score first, regardless of sport. In fact, I wasn't even aware anyone did it differently.

Comment: However. When showing the score *during* a game (at least on TV), the away team is listed first and the home team is listed second.

Comment: @JasonBassford In soccer or baseball? I know it to be true for baseball and (American) football, but I don't think I've ever watched a soccer game.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not certain about North American soccer. But if [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MLS/comments/2aophn/why_is_the_home_team_listed_first/) is any indication, it does specifically follow the European format in the reverse of the other North American sports. (At least in general. Apparently, some networks aren't consistent.)

Comment: What about tennis, where they typically report the scores of all the sets, e.g. *6-4, 2-6, 6-3*. Is the match winner first? Does this differ between US and Europe?

Comment: @Barmar The match winner is shown first. (Although it could be winner 4-6, 6-2, 6-3.) But during the match, where they show one player name above the other, the name on top is normally the player seeded (ranked) highest. I've noticed no difference between any of the tournaments in any of the countries.

Comment: @JasonBassford Well, during an individual game, it is the server's score that is first.  But tennis the soring system is rather different, as it is in sports like golf, cricket etc. It would make no sense whatever to follow the football pattern.

Comment: +1 and a tick for a comprehensive answer. It is exactly the information I was seeking. But what do you do if the match ends in a draw?

Comment: @ws2 In tennis, there are two different scores. One is for the match itself (which I assumed was the most relevant), and the other is for a specific game. And in the event of a tie (not in tennis, of course), I'm guessing that the same order is used as during a game, not afterwards when a winner is known.

Comment: @WS2 most American sports don't conventionally end in a draw. I'm not sure in that case, I suspect it would go away-home, following the baseball convention

Comment: Football (the American sport) and soccer have become national and international sports with improved communications.  There's really no home team at the World Cup or the SuperBowl.

Comment: @Xanne But as far as the World Cup is concerned (also any domestic matches in Britain, played on a neutral ground, such as the FA Cup)  the order in which the teams names are read out is fixed at the time of the draw. And it stays the same irrespective of who wins, or whether the match ends in a draw.